# vbscript how to capture URL from location box in Internet Explorer

Tags: url, dom, vbscript, internet-explorer-8, innertext

In a recent question, [vbscript using InStr to find info that varies within a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20378751/vbscript-using-instr-to-find-info-that-varies-within-a-url), I had asked about finding info in a URL. I later realized I didn't need to find the info in the URL, I just needed to be able to capture the URL from the location box in Internet Explorer and be able to use it to gather data from a web page. Here's what I have so far:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objIE, objShell, objShellWindows
Dim strIDNum, strURL, strWindow, strURLFound, WShell, i

'=============================================================

'===  Code for capturing URL of current page will go here  ===

'=============================================================

strURL = 'URL that is captured by the above coding
strWindow = "Workflow Process"
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows
Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strURLFound = False

'To fix item not found error
For Each objIE in objShellWindows
Next

For i = 0 to objShellWindows.Count - 1
    Set objIE = objShellWindows.Item(i)
On Error Resume Next
    If InStr(Ucase(objShellWindows.Item(i).LocationURL), Ucase(strURL)) Then
        If InStr(Ucase(objShellWindows.Item(i).FullName), "IEXPLORE.EXE") Then
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                If InStr(objShellWindows.Item(i).document.title, (strWindow)) Then
                    strURLFound = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Once I have the URL for the site my users will be on, I will be using the code below to gather the info:

```
WShell.AppActivate strWindow

WScript.Sleep 300

strIDNum = objIE.document.getElementByID("ID_PlaceHolder").value
```

How do I go about getting the URL from the page they are on?

Comment: Don't do an unconditional `WScript.Sleep 300`, that's nonsense. Use a `While Not objIE.document.readyState = "Complete"` loop instead. ([`readyState` on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534359(v=vs.85).aspx))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to get information from another web site with a URL that changes. First, I needed the base URL to at least get me there, once found, it really didn't matter what additional info was in the URL because each page is set up the same, just different data flowing through it. The end result is the code below.

```
Option Explicit
Dim objIE, objShell, objShellWindows
Dim strIDNum, strURL, strWindow, strURLFound, WShell, i

strURL = "http://www.myworkplace.com"
strWindow = "Workflow Process"
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows
Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strURLFound = False

'To fix item not found error
For Each objIE in objShellWindows
Next

For i = 0 to objShellWindows.Count - 1
    Set objIE = objShellWindows.Item(i)
On Error Resume Next
    If InStr(Ucase(objShellWindows.Item(i).LocationURL), Ucase(strURL)) Then
        If InStr(Ucase(objShellWindows.Item(i).FullName), "IEXPLORE.EXE") Then
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                If InStr(objShellWindows.Item(i).document.title, (strWindow)) Then
                    strURLFound = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next

WShell.AppActivate strWindow

WScript.Sleep 300

strIDNum = objIE.document.getElementByID("ID_PlaceHolder").innertext
```

As you can see in the last line, I also used `innertext` rather than `value` to get the ID number.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `objIE.LocationURL`?  Also, thanks to Tomalak for providing `objIE.document.location.href`.

Comment: Alternatively `objIE.document.location.href`, just what one would do in JavaScript. The API is exactly the same, after all.

Comment: See my original message. `objIE.LocationURL` is close, but it doesn't print into the msgbox. Am I missing something?

Comment: ahhh, you changed your question after I posted my answer.  Originally you had `strIDNum = objIE.document.getElementByID("ID_PlaceHolder").value` in place of `msgbox objIE.LocationURL`.  The issue you have in your sample code is that you're creating a brand new IE object (e.g. you're code is essentially "opening" a new hidden IE window) which doesn't have a URL yet when you print it.  It should work if you call it on an existing IE window.

Comment: Yes, I changed it because I couldn't figure out how to put the code here. Above is how I'm gathering the info from the web site. Below is the code I tried and it didn't work. I can't have the URL in the code. I need to get it and save it to a variable.

`Dim objIE`

`Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`

`msgbox objIE.LocationURL`